# Are answers recommending unreleased, unannounced hardware allowed?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, answers

Prompted by [this answer to What's a good life-proof Android phone?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/208/1):

> The upcoming Moto X Force is the phone that sound like the perfect fit(its not revealed or released yet!)
>
> Watch out! These are just leaks and rumors so nothing final yet!
>
> [...rumored specs...]
>
> So if you can wait and you'r willing to spend around 560€ that phone will be great for you!

Are these kind of answers allowed? What if the leaks/rumors are wrong?

Comment: There's a policy that we can likely adapt from Ask Different, that concerns unreleased, or beta software and hardware. That policy disallows those sorts of questions.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'm not talking about questions, but answers :) I don't think we'll have to deal with questions asking about unreleased stuff - they'd be off topic, period.

Comment: Darn it, add answers to that too -_- |

Comment: I'd be more inclined to just have our own policy - we're a substantially different site, with completely different types of questions - and we're only dealing with answers, not questions as they do. I'm glad you mentioned AD's policy, though, as an at least tangentially related precedent for these kind of posts :)

Comment: Ah no, I just linked to it just to make people aware of it.

Answer (score 9):

I see nothing wrong with recommending *unreleased* hardware that is expected to become available in the near future ("wait a week: NVidia's new line of graphics cards will be out, and the GeForce 68040 looks like it'll be what you want").

*Unannounced* hardware is a different matter.  If it hasn't been announced, it effectively doesn't exist, and its specifications are subject to change without notice.  Something that looks like a perfect fit on paper today might be totally inappropriate six months from now, when the actual product hits the shelves.

In between is announced-but-not-available-for-a-while-yet products: They may be delayed, or the specs changed, or canceled entirely (Duke Nukem Forever, anyone?).

I think the dividing line between "acceptable" and "unacceptable" for recommending future products is "are advance copies in the hands of reviewers yet?".  Once people are starting to write reviews of the product, the nature of it can't really change.

Comment: I think it should only be acceptable once there are reviews, as future specs don't tell you how good a product really is. The design might be completely flawed.

Comment: "In between is announced-but-not-available-for-a-while-yet products" - I think this is a perfect reason to **NOT** allow unreleased hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a good answer should be "in the future, X might be available."

If I'm reading this, I want an answer to:

- What is the hardware that will address my question, *now*?

not in the future, not maybe, not potentially, but now. Speculative answers are not going to be helpful to that end.

Answer (score -2):

Its my post thats beeing discussed here and I would say recommending unreleased or in this case not even unannounced hardware should be allowed.

The phone was leaked a lot so that some drastic things on the spec sheet will change is unlikely. Its likely that it will be released at the end of the year and yes there are some months till december but why shouldn't i recommend the clearly perfect fit for the user just because it isn't offical yet. I've said that he needs to wait if he wants this device so if he needs a phone now he must get another one.

The user had a clear list of what things the phone should feature and there aren't that much shock resistent and water-proof phones(as you can see in the post there are not that many answers) and if there are some huge leakes about a  device that will fit everything he wants why shouldn't i be allowed to tell him? Should i rather recommend a device that may survive some water or some drops that maybe isn't high end level like he wants or should I say him "hey look there is a high end device made by Motorola thats build to survive drops and can even drop 1 meter under water and will be fine afterwards but its not released or officaly announced yet so you might need to wait and the specs and price might change a bit?

I don't understand why we shouldn't be allowed to recommend unannounced devices for example the Nexus 5x(or 2015 name not confirmed yet) isn't announced yet but we know alot about it so we can already say if you want to buy a good phone for under 400€/$ maybe you should look out for the Nexus 5x and wait for the google event.

I would say if we mention that it isn't confirmed yet and that things could change and that we can't give the user a guarantee that the hardware we recommend will be exactly like this then recommending unreleased and even unannounced hardware is not bad imo its even better so he gets more input to choose from.

*Feel free to edit grammar or spelling mistakes beacause english is not my native language and i still need to improve wiriting and speaking(understanding works perfectly for me)*

Comment: One of the requirements is "decent photos".  Until there are reviews, you won't be able to tell if they got the camera right: for example, they may have sacrificed low-light performance to get all 21 megapixels on the sensor.

Comment: @Mark i just thought this is the best answer and the only phone that i would recommend for his preferences.